# Python passing array from function to function

Tags: python, pandas

Can't find any solution written in last few years.

I'm looking to pass a variable from one function to another, without needing to rerun the SQL connection.

The first function is:

```
def SQL_Country():
    conn = psq.connect("localhost","root","root","world",cursorclass=psq.cursors.DictCursor)
    query = "SELECT * FROM country"

    with conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        country = cursor.fetchall()

        global df 
        df = pd.DataFrame(country, columns=["Code", "Name", "Continent", "Population", "HeadOfState"])
```

The second function, where I'm looking to pass the output of `SQL_Country()` is:

```
def assignment():

    ## do something here

    elif Choice == 6:
        try:
            x = df
        except NameError:
            x = None

        if x is None:

            print()

            df = SQL_Country(df)
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
  File "Python.py", line 185, in assignment
    df = SQL_Country(df)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df' referenced before assignment
```

Any recommendations on how to pass the outputs from one function to the other?

Comment: This is kind of confusing. Why do you call `SQL_Country(df)` when the function `SQL_Country` doesn't take nay arguments? Stop using `global`, you need to return the df from the first function and input it as argument to the second

Comment: Why not just return df from SQL_Country()?

Comment: How to pass data between functions hasn't ever changed in python. Why does it matter how old the solution is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to rerun the `SQL_Country()` function a second time as `df` is already set.  So I would make a check to see if it has already been set and if so, just return it.  Start by defining df outside the function rather than using the global value.

```
df_country = None

def SQL_Country():
    if df_country is None:
        conn = psq.connect("localhost","root","root","world",cursorclass=psq.cursors.DictCursor)
        query = "SELECT * FROM country"

        with conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(query)
            country = cursor.fetchall()

            df_country = pd.DataFrame(country, columns=["Code", "Name", "Continent", "Population", "HeadOfState"])
    return df_country
```

Now when you call the function it won't execute it the second time, but you'll get the value you were looking for

```
def assignment():
    ## do something here
    if Choice == 6:
         # No need to do the name check
        x = SQL_Country()
        if x is None:
            print()
```

Answer (score 2):

The second function is missing argument:

```
def assignment(df):
```

Comment: Although you define the df to be global, that is not activated until the function is called.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than global you should return df inside SQL_County:

```
        global df 
        df = pd.DataFrame(country, columns=["Code", "Name", "Continent", "Population", "HeadOfState"])
```

should be:

```
        return pd.DataFrame(country, columns=["Code", "Name", "Continent", "Population", "HeadOfState"])
```

and then use:

```
df = SQL_Country()
```

If you want to cache the result of df, I'd use lru_cache:

```
import functools

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=1)
def SQL_Country():
   ...
```

that way the database fetch is only done the once.

---

```
In [11]: @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=1)
         def foo():
             print(1)
             return 2

In [12]: foo()
1
Out[12]: 2

In [13]: foo()
Out[13]: 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should [review python functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm).

You are defining a function with

```
def SQL_Country():
```

Yet when you go to use the function you are supplying an argument (that is not expected as a function input) at:

```
df = SQL_Country(df)
```

Additionally your function:

```
def assignment():
```

probably should also take an input of a dataframe which would make it look like:

```
def assignment(df):
```

at which point the subsequent call to your function would be:

```
assignment(df)
```

Instead of

```
assignment()
```